# Currency icon result MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to create a currency icon (like € or $) in front of the numbers that are returned from the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Aantal reizen', MIN(prijs) AS 'Laagste prijs', MAX(prijs AS 'Hoogste prijs', ROUND(AVG(prijs),0) AS 'Gemiddelde prijs' FROM reizen
```

Is there a data type for this or is there a way around?

Comment: There is no CURRENCY data type, in case you are searching for that. Below are some good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`CONCAT()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for this

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)   AS 'Aantal reizen',
  CONCAT('€ ', MIN(prijs)) AS 'Laagste prijs',
  CONCAT('€ ', MAX(prijs)) AS 'Hoogste prijs', 
  CONCAT('€ ', ROUND(AVG(prijs), 0)) AS 'Gemiddelde prijs' 
FROM reizen
```

From MySQL's documentation on CONCAT():

> **CONCAT(str1,str2,...,strN)**
>
> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May
>   have one or more arguments. If all arguments are nonbinary strings,
>   the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary
>   strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is
>   converted to its equivalent nonbinary string form.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `CONCAT()` function ([here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-concat-function.htm) you get a good explanation).

In your case use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)   AS 'Aantal reizen', CONCAT('€ ', MIN(prijs)) AS 'Laagste prijs', CONCAT('€ ', MAX(prijs)) AS 'Hoogste prijs', CONCAT('€ ', ROUND(AVG(prijs), 0)) AS 'Gemiddelde prijs' FROM reizen
```